# Python If statement returns False, when comparing identical strings

Tags: python

Hello I have a problem with some of my code. I am making a log in/registration program with TKinter, were a user can register and the user info is saved in a .txt file, and then I want   to read the user info and check if the saved usernam and password is the same as LUsername_entry and LPassword_entry.

I want the if statement to print "You are logging in!" since every variable in the if statement are identical strings, but is just prints the else.

I don't get any error codes. I have tried .replace id there is a space, and checking the type of all variables.

txt file:

```
User
Password
```

Code:

```
def login_user():
  global LUsername_entry, LPassword_entry

  f = open("users/user.txt", "r")
  SUsername = f.readline()
  SPassword = f.readline()
  f.close

  if LUsername_entry.get() == SUsername and LPassword_entry.get() == SPassword:
      print("You are logging in!")
  else:
      print("your not logging in...")
```

Comment: `readline()` keeps the newline character at the end. You need to `.strip()` the string before comparing it. Also, you're missing the parentheses after `f.close`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution according to the comments:

```
def login_user():
  global LUsername_entry, LPassword_entry

  with open("users/user.txt", "r") as f:
      tmp = [element.strip() for element in f]

  if LUsername_entry.get() == tmp[0] and LPassword_entry.get() == tmp[1]:
      print("You are logging in!")
  else:
      print("your not logging in...")
```